# Macbook Apache folders

Tags: php, macos, apache

I'm running a localhost in my macbook and I have my server running great under

/Library/WebServer/Documents

I have a php project at /some/path/in/my/macbook/index.php.

how can I make it run under localhost/~myUserName ?

Answer (score 0):

Move your project to unde `/Library/WebServer/Documents` folder.
The default Apache root folder (localhost/) is /Library/WebServer/Documents

Comment: I don't want to do that, i want to redirect a site to a local folder in my HD